# How to create Read_More and Read_less button in Slatejs

Tags: reactjs, slatejs

[In this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_read_more) you can find the read_more/read_less functionality, but in slatejs we don't have direct access to the text. So, how to create that functionality in saltejs in the slatejs way.
I tried to create use ref

```
  const dots = React.useRef<any>();
  const moreText = React.useRef<any>();
  const btnText = React.useRef<any>();
```

then I implemented this way

```
<span ref={dots}>...</span>
      <span ref={moreText}>
        <Editable
          readOnly={readOnly}
          renderElement={renderElement}
          renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
          placeholder="Enter some rich text…"
          spellCheck
          autoFocus
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
        />
      </span>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (dots.current.style.display === "none") {
            dots.current.style.display = "inline";
            btnText.current.innerHTML = "Read less";
            moreText.current.style.display = "inline";
          } else {
            dots.current.style.display = "none";
            btnText.current.innerHTML = "Read more";
            moreText.current.style.display = "none";
          }
        }}
        ref={btnText}
      >
        Read more
      </button>
```

But it hides all the text.
However, I think I need to do sotmihng like `moreText.current.lenghth(300).appendSpan(span of ref={moreText})`

Comment: do you want reactjs implementation?

Comment: Yes please ReactJS implementation will be better

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working app: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-335bjc)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";
const article = {
  title: "Read More Read Less Button",
  disc:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta."
};

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{article.title}</h1>
      <p>{show ? article.disc : article.disc.substr(0, 100) + "..."}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
        {!show ? "Read More" : "Read Less"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This does not work with slatejs. Do you know what is Slatejs?

Comment: I have not played with Slatejs yet. But as requested I have posted the ReactJS solution. If possible, set up the project on stackblitz or codesandbox, won't be much difficult to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on Slatejs and everywhere else.

```
export default function App() {
  const editorRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <div>
 <p
        style={{
          overflow: "hidden",
          textOverflow: "ellipsis",
          display: "-webkit-box",
          WebkitLineClamp: 2,
          WebkitBoxOrient: "vertical"
        }}
        ref={editorRef}
      >
        {article.disc}
      </p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          editorRef.current.style.WebkitLineClamp =
            editorRef.current.style.WebkitLineClamp == false ? 2 : null;
        }}
      >
        toggle
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e5trmb)